# I need the function describing this curve.

Tags: functions, curves

I need a function that describes this curve:

[image]

going through zero and never reaching -1 or 1. 
Thank you for help :)

Comment: Check out the graph of $\arctan$ and see how you can modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: If you want exponential decay of the hiatus try $\tanh$.

Comment: For other functions of this kind see [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) (with $x$ replaced by $\alpha\,x$ if needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of "S"-shaped curve is called a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).  A couple of common sigmoid functions are $\arctan$ and $\operatorname{tanh}$.

So just choose your favorite sigmoid function (or the one that matches your data the best) and then you can modify it by scaling the entire function -- $\alpha \arctan(x)$ -- to make it vertically wider or skinnier or scaling the input variable -- $\arctan(\beta x)$ -- to make it horizontally wider or skinnier.

P.S. That Wikipedia link has this really nice picture of some of the common sigmoid functions that I'll post here:

[image]

Comment: Might be useful: [desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/apj9s36xif)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid fancy things like $\arctan$ or $e$, try the following:
$$\frac{10^x-1}{10^x+1}$$
Really, this is just the $\tanh$ function that others have mentioned, but modified.