# I need a function describing another curve.

Tags: functions, curves

I already asked for a function [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492315/i-need-the-function-describing-this-curve) and the answers where very helpful. But know I need a function for this curve:

[the curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AShjo.png)

It like my first curve but rotated by 90 and inverted horizontally.

Tank you :)

**Update**
The answer *tan(πx/2)* is good. But I need to modify this curve to be sharper (closer to the x axis for low values) and I currently do not get to modify it like this.

Comment: going through zero and reaching infinity for x < -1 and x > +1. Thank you for help :)

Comment: $tan(\pi x/2)$ will fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since tan(x) goes through (0, 0), goes to infinity as x goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and goes to negative infinity as x goes to $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $y= tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ should do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Another obvious option would be $\text{arctanh }x$.